# How to run through each loop for cell reference with button in VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have the below code for looping row by row to update the references of cells from one sheet to another.

```
Public Sub Update()    
Dim i As Integer

     For i = 2 To Sheet1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     Sheet2.[B4] = Sheet1.Range("B" & i)
     Sheet2.[B5] = Sheet1.Range("C" & i)
     Sheet2.[B6] = Sheet1.Range("D" & i)

     Next i
    End Sub
```

How can I create a button so that every time I click, the cell will update by one row?

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps to add button and then you can add your code.

> 1. Go to Developer Tab in Excel(Version 2010), click on Form Controls and then add button.
> 2. After adding right click on button and then click Assign macro.
> 3. You can assign existing macro or create new.

if you are using some other version, then form controls can be in Insert tab.